# How to figure out "progress" while sorting?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, progress

I'm using `stable_sort` to sort a large `vector`.

The sorting takes on the order of a few seconds (say, 5-10 seconds), and I would like to display a progress bar to the user showing how much of the sorting is done so far.

But (even if I was to write my own sorting routine) how can I tell how much progress I have made, and how much more there is left to go?

I don't need it to be exact, but I need it to be "reasonable" (i.e. reasonably linear, not faked, and certainly not backtracking).

Comment: If you know the time complexity of the sorting algorithm, you can estimate the average number of steps required for the size of the array. If N steps are required, then bump the progress bar by 100/N% after each step.

Comment: @Barmar: I have no idea what the constant factor is, though.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that, either. Perhaps you can determine it empirically, by running the algorithm over a few random datasets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard library sort uses a user-supplied comparison function, so you can insert a comparison counter into it. The total number of comparisons for either quicksort/introsort or mergesort will be very close to log<sub>2</sub>N * N (where N is the number of elements in the vector). So that's what I'd export to a progress bar: number of comparisons / N*log<sub>2</sub>N

Since you're using mergesort, the comparison count will be a very precise measure of progress. It might be slightly non-linear if the implementation spends time permuting the vector between comparison runs, but I doubt your users will see the non-linearity (and anyway, we're all used to inaccurate non-linear progress bars :) ).

Quicksort/introsort would show more variance, depending on the nature of the data, but even in that case it's better than nothing, and you could always add a fudge factor on the basis of experience.

A simple counter in your compare class will cost you practically nothing. Personally I wouldn't even bother locking it (the locks would hurt performance); it's unlikely to get into an inconsistent state, and anyway the progress bar won't go start radiating lizards just because it gets an inconsistent progress number.

Comment: @Mehrdad: with mergesort, it really shouldn't be necessary. The fact that the time mergesort takes varies depending on use of auxiliary memory doesn't affect the number of comparisons it makes, so tracking comparisons should be extremely accurate, although slightly non-linear with storage effects.

Comment: Yup, sounds reasonable... I'll code it up and see how it goes.

Comment: Using this formula and std::sort of a deque, my sorts go to ~200%. Guess I gotta divide by two.

Answer (score 1):

Split the vector into several equal sections, the quantity depending upon the granularity of progress reporting you desire.  Sort each section seperately.  Then start merging with `std::merge`.  You can report your progress after sorting each section, and after each merge.  You'll need to experiment to determine how much percentage the sorting of the sections should be counted compared to the mergings.

**Edit:**

I did some experiments of my own and found the merging to be insignificant compared to the sorting, and this is the function I came up with:

```
template<typename It, typename Comp, typename Reporter>
void ReportSort(It ibegin, It iend, Comp cmp, Reporter report, double range_low=0.0, double range_high=1.0)
{
    double range_span = range_high - range_low;
    double range_mid = range_low + range_span/2.0;
    using namespace std;
    auto size = iend - ibegin;
    if (size < 32768) {
       stable_sort(ibegin,iend,cmp);        
    } else {
        ReportSort(ibegin,ibegin+size/2,cmp,report,range_low,range_mid);
        report(range_mid);
        ReportSort(ibegin+size/2,iend,cmp,report,range_mid,range_high);
        inplace_merge(ibegin, ibegin + size/2, iend);
    }   
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(100000000);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());

    std::cout << "starting...\n";

    double percent_done = 0.0;
    auto report = [&](double d) {
        if (d - percent_done >= 0.05) {
            percent_done += 0.05;
            std::cout << static_cast<int>(percent_done * 100) << "%\n";
        }
    };
    ReportSort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::less<int>(), report);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it: sort a small vector and extrapolate the time assuming O(n log n) complexity.

t(n) = C * n * log(n) ⇒ t(n<sub>1</sub>) / t(n<sub>2</sub>) = n<sub>1</sub>/n<sub>2</sub> * log(n<sub>1</sub>)/log(n<sub>2</sub>)

If sorting 10 elements takes 1 μs, then 100 elements will take 1 μs * 100/10 * log(100)/log(10) = 20 μs.

Answer (score 0):

Stable sort is based on merge sort. If you wrote your own version of merge sort then (ignoring some speed-up tricks) you would see that it consists of log N passes. Each pass starts with 2^k sorted lists and produces 2^(k-1) lists, with the sort finished when it merges two lists into one. So you could use the value of k as an indication of progress.

If you were going to run experiments, you might instrument the comparison object to count the number of comparisons made and try and see if the number of comparisons made is some reasonably predictable multiple of n log n. Then you could keep track of progress by counting the number of comparisons done.

(Note that with the C++ stable sort, you have to hope that it finds enough store to hold a copy of the data. Otherwise the cost goes from N log N to perhaps N (log N)^2 and your predictions will be far too optimistic).

Answer (score 0):

Select a small subset of indices and count inversions. You know its maximal value, and you know when you are done the value is zero. So, you can use this value as a "progressor". You can think of it as a measure of entropy.

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort is basically

1. partition input using a pivot element
2. sort smallest part recursively
3. sort largest part using tail recursion

All the work is done in the partition step. You could do the outer partition directly and then report progress as the smallest part is done.
So there would be an additional step between 2 and 3 above.

- Update progressor

Here is some code.

```
template <typename RandomAccessIterator>
void sort_wReporting(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
{
double done = 0;
double whole = static_cast<double>(std::distance(first, last));

typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type value_type;

while (first != last && first + 1 != last)
{
    auto d = std::distance(first, last);
    value_type pivot = *(first + std::rand() % d);

    auto iter = std::partition(first, last, 
        [pivot](const value_type& x){ return x < pivot; });
    auto lower = distance(first, iter);
    auto upper = distance(iter, last);
    if (lower < upper)
    {
        std::sort(first, iter);
        done += lower;
        first = iter;
    }
    else
    {
        std::sort(iter, last);
        done += upper;
        last = iter;
    }

    std::cout << done / whole << std::endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost one day to figure out how to display the progress for shell sort, so I will leave here my simple formula. Given an array of colors, it will display the progress. It is blending the colors from red to yellow and then to green. When it is Sorted, it is the last position of the array that is blue. For shell sort, the iterations each time it passes through the array are quite proportional, so the progress becomes pretty accurate.
(Code in Dart/Flutter)

```
List<Color> colors = [
    Color(0xFFFF0000),
    Color(0xFFFF5500),
    Color(0xFFFFAA00),
    Color(0xFFFFFF00),
    Color(0xFFAAFF00),
    Color(0xFF55FF00),
    Color(0xFF00FF00),
    Colors.blue,
  ];
[...]
style: TextStyle(
    color: colors[(((pass - 1) * (colors.length - 1)) / (log(a.length) / log(2)).floor()).floor()]),
```

It is basically a cross-multiplication.
a means array. (log(a.length) / log(2)).floor() means rounding down the log2(N), where N means the number of items. I tested this with several combinations of array sizes, array numbers, and sizes for the array of colors, so I think it is good to go.